# How device name is copied in ip_rt_ioctl in fib_frontend.c

Tags: linux-kernel

I have one doubt in ip_rt_ioctl function

In case of route addition, first a copy_from_user is made for the structure struct rtentry and then the copied data from is subsequently used in rtentry_to_fib_config function, including the rtentry.rt_dev field which usually is the device name.

My understanding is copy_from_user does a shallow copy. So since the rtentry.rt_dev field is again a character pointer. So likely the contents of the pointer will  not get copied.
Hence even after copy the device name will be pointer to the user space address.

So is it right to access the user space address from kernel space ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OK to refer to user-space address from kernel-space while kernel is bound to that process' context (this is true for syscall handlers). In that case, proper page table is set and it's safe to refer to user process' memory.

However, you should always check validity of address or use `copy_from_user()` that does that.